# Ubuntu freezing right after login screen 1 to 2 weeks after fresh install

Tags: drivers, nvidia, freeze

So here's my story. I have an Acer e5-573g notebook for a while now (about 5 years), that was running Windows. About 1 to 2 months ago my HD got burnt and I got it replaced with a SSD and right after it installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 (I'm starting a web development course and there you can't use Windows). It all went well overall on the installation, except for a few things. My microphone's headset ins't recognized and the bluetooth module is blocked after every fresh install, but I already figured out how to manage those things. 
Well, the problem is what comes next. The first fresh install I did went well. Being a newbie at Linux in general, I had a hard time fixing those tweaks but after a couple of days I managed to succeed. And then all of a sudden, about 1 to 2 weeks after the installation my computer just decided to freeze right after the login screen. I could execute 1 basic command and then it froze (like after a cold boot I could open the terminal and write one line of text and then it froze). 
I searched all around askubuntu and other websites for this kind of error and noticed that it was probably due to my Nvidia card. I tried to deactivate it through GRUB but got no success.
Then I did another fresh install and after fixing the headset and bluetooth problem, I went right after the nvidia proprietary drivers and uninstalled them. Heard somewhere that this is a recurrent issue for nvidia people... After kernel updates, they'd stop working and freeze your computer. And then after 1 to 2 weeks, I could say after some days after a random update, my computer suddenly froze again. I couldn't figure it out how to fix it and then fresh installed again.
After this fresh install and fixing the standard issues (damn nobody said it was going to be that hard, huh? ahahah), I completely removed anything that had nvidia written in it. Deactivated it completely and stood with Intel HD graphics integrated card. And then, again, 1 to 2 weeks later (yesterday) the computer suddenly froze a-g-a-i-n the same way. 
I noticed some strange things like sometimes the system would "boot normally" and just after login in it froze and sometimes it had a really fast running screen with "loading some modules, firmwares and other things" (kind of the background operation instead of the little moving circle) and I noticed some errors there but couldn't write them down. Sometimes it shows an firmware error and I rebooted and it just didn't show anymore. Yes, I'm lost. 
Now i'm trying pop_OS but I really got the feeling that I'll have some problems.
My course starts in about 3 weeks, and for now I'm ok doing those fresh installs and fixing and searching around, but eventually I'll need to have a computer that actually works for more than 2 weeks straight ahahah.
So that's what I have to do after every fresh install:

- For the headset, I add the codec to alsa-base.conf and override the jack with hdajackretask. Sometimes it works doing once, sometimes it takes a while and some reboots to work and idk why lol
- For the bluetooth, I blacklist acer_wmi module and reboot and it works.

So, any ideas on what the problem may be? I'm looking for any tips, points of view or suggestions. Maybe a hardware problem? I sincerely don't know. I'm just getting desperate at this point :(.
Thanks!!

Comment: After freezing does it take a long time to shut down. (Press esc to see messages) I had a freeze problem with 20.04, it was cured after a kernel update. Do "uname -a" & tell me your kernel version. Have you done any updates ?

Comment: Try 
Release: 21.04
Codename: hirsute & I prefer Xubuntu. Any over heating in the laptop, blow out vents etc to clear dust. Feel if hot underneath

Comment: Hi, Keith. First of all, thanks for answering me!
My "uname -a" output is
[Linux pop-os 5.11.0-7614-generic #15~1618626693~20.10~ecb25cd-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 22 16:00:45 UTC  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux]
As you can see, I've already switched to another OS hoping it'll help.
I've started the thread to start gathering ideas for the eventual next crash and for helping others that might be having the same issue. I'll surely try 21.04 if anything happens to my pop.

Comment: You could try to install a sensor app, in Ubuntu its psensor. Try to decide if its hardware or software.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I'll look for it right now and try to monitor my current installation. I'll need a way to access the monitoring trough GRUB tho, since when it freezes I don't have time to open any applications. Thanks, man. I really thought no one was going to reply ahahah.

Comment: I have never seen monitoring through grub, but you bios may have CPU temperature info. Also you may be able to clock down your CPU to make it cooler. I had crashes I clocked down from 31X to 30X & its more stable

Comment: So just an update. My pop OS went down the same way. This time I think I may have found a solution. So I found on another page that this was a problem with the partition being corrupted and then I fsck it and managed to fix. But I had my system encrypted and I did something that broke that encryption so I couldn't get pass it. The good news is that I managed to fix the partition without formating it (checked that on recovery mode) so I'd say now that I have no encryption next time it happens i'll be prepared.